# M2.3-ce Failed to set ini option "session.save_path" when use memcached for session

Tags: magento2

`OS-Ubuntu18.04` I configured `php7.2-fpm` with `memcached` for session

```
session.save_handler = "memcached"
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Checked with `cache-test.php`. It was OK.
Configured `Magento`

```
app/etc/env.php
    'session' => [
            'save' => 'memcached',
            'save_path' => '127.0.0.1:11211'
    ],
```

But storefront page throws error

```
InvalidArgumentException: Failed to set ini option "session.save_path" to value "127.0.0.1:11211". in /home/magento/shop1/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:632 Stack trace: #0 ...
```

I tried to use socket, but it didn't help either.

Could you advise how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/memcache/memcache_magento.html the guide is outdated.
It works without 'save_path' => '127.0.0.1:11211' in magento config.

```
app/etc/env.php
    'session' => [
            'save' => 'memcached',      
    ],
```